# Proof for existence of exactly one solution for the number of marbles in each box

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algorithms

> There are four boxes A, B, C and D containing marbles. Two boxes are randomly
>   selected and the number of marbles in each box is summarized. This procedure
>   is repeated five times with the following results: {6586,8192,9014,8225,9831}
>
> Determine the number of marbles inside each of the four boxes.

We’ve got a solution but wonder if more solutions exist and if there’s an
efficient algorithm to calculate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given four boxes of marbles, there are six [${4 \choose 2}$] ways of arranging two-box sums.

We are given five such two-box sums.  Call the sixth, unknown two-box sum $u$.

Let $a$ = the number of marbles in box A, $b$ = the number of marbles in box B, etc., such that $$a <= b <= c <= d \tag{1}$$

Then the six two-box sums are represented by, in some order, $(a + b)$, $(a + c)$, $(a + d)$, $(b + c)$, $(b + d)$ and $(c + d)$.

The six two-box sums are also represented by, in some order, $u$, 6586, 8192, 9014, 8225 and 9831.

The sum of these are equal, such that

$$(a + b) + (a + c) + (a + d) + (b + c) + (b + d) + (c + d) = u + 6586 + 8192 + 9014 + 8225 + 9831$$

Simplifying,

$$3(a + b + c + d) = u + 41848 \tag{2}$$

Looking at our six two-box sums, there are 15 ways to arrange these six values into three two-box sums:

\begin{array}{r l l l l l l}
Way & Group\,G_1 & \sum G_1 & Group\,G_2 & \sum G_2 & Group\,G_3 & \sum G_3 \\
\hline \\
 1. & 6586, 8192 & 14778 & 8225, 9014 & 17239 & 9831, u & 9831 + u \\
 2. & 6586, 8192 & 14778 & 8225, 9831 & 18056 & 9014, u & 9014 + u \\
 3. & 6586, 8192 & 14778 & 8225, u & 8225 + u & 9014, 9831 & 18845 \\
 4. & 6586, 8225 & 14811 & 8192, 9014 & 17206 & 9831, u & 9831 + u \\
 5. & 6586, 8225 & 14811 & 8192, 9831 & 18023 & 9014, u & 9014 + u \\
 6. & 6586, 8225 & 14811 & 8192, u & 8192 + u & 9014, 9831 & 18845 \\
 7. & 6586, 9014 & 15600 & 8192, 8225 & 16417 & 9831, u & 9831 + u \\
 8. & 6586, 9014 & 15600 & 8192, 9831 & 18023 & 8225, u & 8225 + u \\
 9. & 6586, 9014 & 15600 & 8192, u & 8192 + u & 8225, 9831 & 18056 \\
10. & 6586, 9831 & \color{red}{16417} & 8192, 8225 & \color{red}{16417} & 9014, u & \color{red}{9014 + u} \\
11. & 6586, 9831 & 16417 & 8192, 9014 & 17206 & 8225, u & 8225 + u \\
12. & 6586, 9831 & 16417 & 8192, u & 8192 + u & 8225, 9014 & 17239 \\
13. & 6586, u & 6586 + u & 8192, 8225 & 16417 & 9014, 9831 & 18845 \\
14. & 6586, u & 6586 + u & 8192, 9014 & 17206 & 8225, 9831 & 18056 \\
15. & 6586, u & 6586 + u & 8192, 9831 & 18023 & 8225, 9014 & 17239 \\
\end{array}

In one of these fifteen ways, the boxes represented by the each of the three sums $\sum G_i$ are all disjoint, such that 
one of the three groups (could be $G_1$, $G_2$ or $G_3$) represents $(a + b)$ and $(c + d)$, a second group
represents $(a + c)$ and $(b + d)$, and the third group represents $(a + d)$ and $(b + c)$.  In that row out of the fifteen,
$\sum G_1 = \sum G_2 = \sum G_3 = a + b + c + d$.  In only one of the fifteen ways shown are the two $\sum G_i$
values that don't involve unknown $u$ equivalent:  Way #10.  In this row, then, all sums must be equal.

Therefore, $9014 + u = 16417$, so $u = 7403$.

Therefore, the six two-box sums have to be $6586$, $7403$, $8192$, $9014$, $8225$ and $9831$.

By (1), $a$ and $b$ have the fewest marbles, so their two-box sum must be the smallest two-box sum:  $$a + b = 6586 \tag{3}$$

Similarly, $$c + d = 9831 \tag{4}$$, the biggest two-box sum.

That means some combination of the remaining two-box sums (7403 and 9014; 8192 and 8225) must correspond to disjoint pairs [$(a + c)$ and $(b + d)$];[$(a + d)$ and $(b + c)$].

Since, by (1), $(a + c) <= (a + d)$ and $(b + c) <= (b + d)$, there are four possibilities:

Case I.
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a + c = 7403 \\ 
b + d = 9014 \\ 
a + d = 8192 \\
b + c = 8225 \\
a + b = 6586 \\
c + d = 9831 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$$a = 2882, b = 3704, c = 4521, d = 5310$$

Case II.
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a + c = 7403 \\ 
b + d = 9014 \\ 
a + d = 8225 \\
b + c = 8192 \\
a + b = 6586 \\
c + d = 9831 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Results in fractional marbles ($a = 2898.5, b = 3687.5, c = 4504.5, d = 5326.5$).

Case III.
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a + c = 8192 \\ 
b + d = 8225 \\ 
a + d = 9014 \\
b + c = 7403 \\
a + b = 6586 \\
c + d = 9831 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Violates (1), and results in fractional marbles ($a = 3687.5, b = 2898.5, c = 4504.5, d = 5326.5$).

Case IV.
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a + c = 8225 \\ 
b + d = 8192 \\ 
a + d = 9014 \\
b + c = 7403 \\
a + b = 6586 \\
c + d = 9831 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Violates (1) (a = 3704, b = 2882, c = 4521, d = 5310)

So Case I wins the day, and

$$a = 2882, b = 3704, c = 4521, d = 5310$$